# Dates errors in access from vb .net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a access 2012 data base with some data fileds. When I update from a vb .net program the data storage in a crazy way.

If I use a  query as:

```
UPDATE Usuarios SET Fecha1=#01/12/2016# WHERE Id_usuario=101
```

in the database the field show 11-Jan-16

and if I use a query as :

```
UPDATE Usuarios SET Fecha1=#15/12/2016# WHERE Id_usuario=101
```

in the database the field show 15-Dec-16

I mean...it seems like the data base change the date format only if it can. I have tried changing location options, formating, and...nothing. There is any way to be sure my date it will be right write.???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what it shows back in VB or even in the Access IDE is not what it stores (you cant see what it stores).  Dates dont have a format. Is the first example absolutely correct - it looks like it lost a day.  The second one is the the same just displayed differently

Answer (score -1):

Typically MS Access uses american formatting, (mm-dd-yyyy) in the database, or it will use what is your current system's default, which is probably dd-mm-yyyy

To prevent this, you can use the `Format()` function. I use two methods.

Format the date values to`yyyy-mm-dd` because dates written that way are always mm-dd

Comment: _First_, US format is mm/dd/yyyy. _ad 1:_ Use `yyyy\/mm\dd` to force a slash as date separator. _ad 2:_ Don't ever use `mmm` as it is localized and will fail in any non-English environment without adding any advantage at all.